# NoMethodError / undefined method `foobar_path' when using form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using form_for to create a chatroom and when I view the page I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Chatrooms#new 
undefined method `chatrooms_path' for #<#<Class:0xa862b94>:0xa5307f0>
```

Here's the code for the view, located in app/views/chatrooms/new.html.erb:

```
<div class="center">
  <%= form_for(@chatroom) do |f| %>
    <%=f.text_field :topic%>
    <br>
    <%=f.submit "Start a discussion", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary"%>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Here's the relevant controller:

```
class ChatroomsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @chatroom = Chatroom.new
  end

  def show
    @chatroom = Chatroom.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

If I change the line

```
<%= form_for(@chatroom) do |f| %>
```

to

```
<%= form_for(:chatroom) do |f| %>
```

it works fine.
I've searched around for similar questions but none of the solutions have worked for me. Help?

Comment: do you have `resources :chatrooms` in your routes.rb?

Comment: Please post your routes.rb and/or the result of `rake routes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you didn't create route/action for `ChatroomsController`. When you render `new` form it is pointing to create action by default, if you want to change handler action, use

```rails
form_for @chatroom, :url => some_other_path
```